# Loading array from plist file disadvantages?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Instead of using NSUserDefaults to save my arrays, I just save the contents of each array to a plist file, and on launch initialize my arrays with the content of the plist file.

My question is: are there any disadvantages to this approach? Can too many plist files cause speed decreases in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSUserDefaults is based on XML too. The only disadvantage is that you have to implement the read/write methods on your own. I don't think that NSUserDefaults are faster than saving/reading the plist files manually.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, yes, plists can decreases your app speed.
Because if you store a big array in it but you only want to search/load one entry, you always have to load the entire plist for example.
Instead NSUserDefaults are based on XML... Using them you have to write method to save and retrieve data but, with plists, NSArray and NSDictionary classes provide some method like `writeToFile:atomically:`.
if you want to use plists, this document could be useful: [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i)